# How to read the json data file I downloaded from firebase as gson?

Tags: java, firebase-realtime-database, gson

My json file... I'm sure there is no mistake in Json

```
{
        "-MHG5VdrTky1GdpmNLHl": {
            "author_id": "data1",
            "create_date": 1600162233475,
            "display_name": "data1",
            "phone_number": "data1"
        },
        "-MHG5Vdsy6Hd1zrcRkmm": {
            "author_id": "data1",
            "create_date": 1600162233475,
            "display_name": "data1",
            "phone_number": "data1"
        },
        "-MHG5Vdsy6Hd1zrcRkmn": {
            "author_id": "data1",
            "create_date": 1600162233475,
            "display_name": "data1",
            "phone_number": "data1"
        }
}
```

my json file size 1gb. How do I read this file with that Gson?

My read method..

```
  InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(path);
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                List<ContactList> contactListList = new ArrayList<>();
                reader.beginObject();
                while (reader.hasNext()) {
                    ContactList cts = gson.fromJson(reader, ContactList.class);
    //                contactListList.add(cts);
                }
                reader.endArray();
                reader.close();
```

the error i got ::=> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was NAME at line 1 column 3 path $.

My ContactList class That way I cannot read the object.

```
 public class ContactList {
     
        private String author_id;
        private String display_name;
        private String phone_number;
        private long create_date;
     
        public ContactList(){}
     
        public ContactList(String author_id, String display_name, String phone_number, long create_date) {
            this.author_id = author_id;
            this.display_name = display_name;
            this.phone_number = phone_number;
            this.create_date = create_date;
        }
     
        public String getAuthor_id() {
            return author_id;
        }
     
        public void setAuthor_id(String author_id) {
            this.author_id = author_id;
        }
     
        public String getDisplay_name() {
            return display_name;
        }
     
        public void setDisplay_name(String display_name) {
            this.display_name = display_name;
        }
     
        public String getPhone_number() {
            return phone_number;
        }
     
        public void setPhone_number(String phone_number) {
            this.phone_number = phone_number;
        }
     
        public long getCreate_date() {
            return create_date;
        }
     
        public void setCreate_date(long create_date) {
            this.create_date = create_date;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Almost sure your issue is that you have a different object receiving than your ContactList, could you share your ContactList.class?

Comment: If you have additional information to add to the question, edit it using the edit link at the bottom.  Do not provide links to code.  Everything must be in the question itself.

Comment: of course I'm editing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a working around fix, but you need to go for each object that you have and add it manually, since you don't know the object name.

```
while (reader.hasNext())
    {
        String name = reader.nextName();
        String author_id = "";
        String create_date = "";
        String display_name = "";
        String phone_number = "";

        if (name.equals("author_id"))
        {
            author_id = reader.nextString();
        }
        else if (name.equals("create_date"))
        {
            create_date = String.valueOf(reader.nextLong());
        }
        else if (name.equals("display_name"))
        {
            display_name = reader.nextString();
        }
        else if (name.equals("phone_number"))
        {
            phone_number = reader.nextString();
        }
        else
        {
            reader.skipValue();
        }

        ContactList contactList = new ContactList(author_id, create_date, display_name, 0L);
        contactListArray.add(contactList);
    }
```

I think you can work with this!! I hope you get it running!!

Comment: very well, thank you.. problem is
`String name = reader.nextName();`